# A balanced die is rolled twice. Let X be the result of the first throw and let Y be the greater of the two results.

Tags: probability, probability-theory

A balanced die is rolled twice. Let X be the result of the first throw and let Y be the greater of the two results.

$a)$ Calculate $\rho (X, Y)$

$(b)$ Calculate $E[Y\mid X=3]$

I believe that X and Y take the values $1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6$. But now I am confused in calculating the probabilities. For example, $P(X=5, Y=1)=0$? Although I am not sure if it is necessary to calculate this possibility, and then, should I calculate the possibilities $P(X=1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6)$, $P(Y=1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)$ and $P(XY=)$?

Comment: $P(X = x, Y = y) = P(Y = y | X = x) \cdot P(X = x)$. and $P(X = x) = 1/6$ for all $x \in (1, 6)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a) Let $Z$ denote the result of the second throw. Then $X, Z$ are independent and $Y = \max \{X, Z\}$. Rephrase the event $\{ X = x, Y = y \}$ using $X, Z$ only and then use independence of $X, Z$ to calculate the according probability.

b) We have
$$
\mathbb{E}\left[Y \, \vert \, X = 3 \right]
= \sum_{y = 1}^{6}{y \, \mathbb{P}(Y = y \, \vert \, X = 3)}\\
=\sum_{y = 1}^{6}{y \, \frac{\mathbb{P}(Y = y, X = 3)}{\mathbb{P}(X = 3)}}.
$$

Comment: I have had a hard time calculating the covariance, how do I calculate E(XY)?

For (b), E(Y|X=3)=4?

Comment: You already calculated the joint distribution of $X$ and $Y$ in a), so $\mathbb{E}\left[XY\right] = \sum_{x = 1}^{6}\sum_{y = 1}^{6}{xy\, \mathbb{P}(X = x, Y = y)}$. For b), I don't want to calculate...but that $4$ sounds at least somewhat plausible.